# Best practice for using AWS and serverless CLIs for both professional and educational projects from the same computer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I am using AWS and serverless framwork at work. Work credentials are stored in the `~/.aws/credentials` file.

What is best practice to be able to use the AWS and serverless CLI from the same computer account without risking deploying my educational projects to the work account, or even worse, deploying work stuff on my educational account.

It can't be that I always need to specify the credentials I want to use whever I write an aws/serverless command, because sometime I will forget. It is okay if using the cli tools in the educational project becomes more cumbersome.

Comment: I personally create named profiles in the credentials file, and I always specify a profile name with every command I run.

Comment: If you don't want to rely on different credentials profiles, then maybe you should create two users for your computer (work and home). Then each can use the default credentials. Better yet, you should use two distinct computers. You should probably do that anyway as your employer may have some legal rights to work *you* create on *their* computer.

Answer (score 0):

All your risk is coming from the fact that you are wanting to do demos using your personal AWS account with your work computer. I for example have a profile on my work computer, which relates to a limited read only role of my personal AWS account to some code commit repos and s3 buckets. Any more than that would be a risk, and depending on the organization you work for, completely unacceptable.

The best solution would be that your work gives you a sandbox account for you to demo and play around with. This is what my work does as well. I would fully pursue that avenue before going ahead using your own account.

If you do go ahead with using your own account there are a few choices. Profiles have been around for a while and that has been mentioned. But personally I have found it easy to make a mistake. Limiting permissions of your cli to your work account will mitigate this. Doing a `Read` operation on the wrong account is not as bad as deleting something. But I've found that some cli tools will have different conventions with what profile they use, so this can be dangerous.

IMO the best option is to Configure [AWS SSO](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-sso.html). Long-lived `iam` CLI users are considered bad practice anyway, and since AWS has come out with this you could even say they are redundant. Now with the new version of the CLI you can sign in to an AWS account, from the CLI via an SSO page with optional MFA enabled, so you don't need `CLI` users in `iam`. This way you don't need to store any long-lived CLI credentials, or remember a profile. Sign into one AWS account at a time and you will be signed in for an hour. This minimizes the chances of you performing actions in the wrong account, and there will be no risk of accidentally using the wrong profile. If you come back to your computer the next day, run some CLI command before remembering to specify the correct account, it won't matter because you will not be signed in. You need to keep in mind that with this approach you might have 2 different `SSO` pages (one for personal and one for work), and you also need your work account to configure `SSO`.